# Alternative solutions for using native APIs: JVM_LoadClass0, JVM_AllocateNewArray and JVM_AllocateNewObject

Tags: java, c++, c, jvm, java-9

As in Java 9 some native APIs were removed for being deprecated, I didn't manage to find alternative solutions to replace them. I am a C++ developer, with little experience in java. The native APIs that I am using are: `JVM_LoadClass0`, `JVM_AllocateNewObject` and `JVM_AllocateNewArray`.

My source code in Java is:

```
protected Class resolveClass(MercObjectStreamClass v) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    /* Resolve by looking up the stack for a non-zero class
     * loader. If not found use the system loader.
     */
    String name = v.getName();
    try
    {
        //we are using the loadClass0 method which calls the native JVM_LoadClass0
        //JVM_LoadClass0 is deprecated and we need to replace the call
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      if(loader == null) {
          return loadClass0(null,name);
        }

      Class scriptCls =  loader.loadClass(scriptClassname);
        return loadClass0(scriptCls,name);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Class cl = (Class)primClasses.get(name);
        if (cl != null)
            return cl;
        else
            throw ex;
    }
}
private native Class loadClass0(Class cl, String classname) throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

And then the native code is just a simple call to JVM_LoadClass0:

```
JNIEXPORT jclass JNICALL
Java_mercio_MercObjectInputStream_loadClass0(JNIEnv * env,
    jobject this,
    jclass curClass,
    jstring currClassName)
{
    return JVM_LoadClass0(env, this, curClass, currClassName);
}
```

The native part is similar to the other APIs.

Can someone suggest an alternative to this approach?

Comment: Looks worth a read: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4249833

Comment: Even Java 6 [doesn’t list these functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html), so it’s hard to suggest a replacement without knowing what these functions were supposed to do. What is that `resolveClass` method supposed to do? Why doesn’t it simply call `loadClass` on the `ClassLoader`?

Comment: Self-advertising, but I guess it can serve your needs: https://github.com/nokia/cppJNI

Comment: The JVM_* functions that you found in jvm.h are not a supported/documented interface so they can change at any time. Better to stick with the JNI interface where you will find functions such as FindClass and AllocObect.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve looked up the source code of `JVM_LoadClass0` and found the following comment

```
// Load a class relative to the most recent class on the stack  with a non-null
// classloader.
// This function has been deprecated and should not be considered part of the
// specified JVM interface.
```

The purpose of the additional `currClass` parameter can only guessed from the actual code, but apparently “the most recent class on the stack” is only used if `currClass` is not `null`, otherwise the loader of `currClass` is used.

This raises some questions about the intention of the `resolveClass` method.

- In a normal environment, a custom class like your `MercObjectInputStream` should not be loaded by the bootstrap loader, hence, the most recent class on the stack with a non-null classloader should be your own `MercObjectInputStream` class. Using your own class’ loader for resolving a class is quiet easy, you can simply call `Class.forName(name)`.
- You are probing `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` which defaults to `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` and is rarely set to `null`. So the behavior of probing the classes on stack seems to be a rare corner case anyway.
- When the context loader is not `null`, you are not using it to load the class, but rather do `loader.loadClass(scriptClassname); return loadClass0(scriptCls,name);`, loading a `scriptClassname` first and use the result’s loader to resolve `name`. If that’s intentional, you can use `Class<?> scriptCls = loader.loadClass(scriptClassname); return Class.forName(name, true, scriptCls.getClassLoader());` to achieve the same without native methods.

You can do exactly the same as the original code in Java 9 without native code using

```
protected Class resolveClass(MercObjectStreamClass v)
                                       throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    String name = v.getName();
    try
    {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(loader != null)
            loader = loader.loadClass(scriptClassname).getClassLoader();
        else
            loader = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE)
                        .walk(s -> s.map(sf -> sf.getDeclaringClass().getClassLoader())
                                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                    .findFirst().orElse(null));

        return Class.forName(name, true, loader);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Class cl = (Class)primClasses.get(name);
        if (cl != null)
            return cl;
        else
            throw ex;
    }
}
```

but, as said, you should first rethink what the method actually is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi, could this be a code that can be compiled with java 6, as it should run with any kind of java from 6 on? Thanks.

Comment: @istik unfortunately not, `StackWalker` is a Java 9 feature and there’s no (standard) Java 6 feature capable of doing the caller-sensitive operation. But as explained in the answer, you should reconsider whether this caller-sensitivity is really required, as it doesn’t seem to apply in practical scenarios anyway.

Comment: You are right, I never managed to obtain a scenario in which it reaches that branch. So thank you for that. I also managed to solve the `VM_AllocateNewObject` issue with the `AllocObject` JNI call. The only one I have left is the `JVM_AllocateNewArray`. I am still not able to obtain the same result as with it in an earlier java version.

Comment: There is a comment before calling the native method saying:                                                                   
                `/* This can't be done with new because only the top level array
   * is needed and the type must be set properly.
   * the lower level arrays will be created when they are read.
   */`                                                                                             I'm wondering if I should open a new topic for that.

Comment: If you write `new Type[size][][]`, only the “top level array” will be created, in contrast to `new Type[size1][size2][size3]`, which creates a bunch of sub-arrays. To my understanding, `JNI_NewObjectArray` also creates the “top level array” only (as it doesn’t even have a parameter for sub-dimensions).

Answer (score 3):

[This doc page at oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html) contains complete list of JNI functions that are available in Java 9.

By looking at the old JNI functions you mentioned, I guess you may be particularly interested in:

- [class operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#class-operations) (`DefineClass()`, `FindClass()`, ...)
- [object operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#object-operations) (`AllocObject()`, `NewObject()`, ...)
- [array operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#array-operations) (`NewObjectArray()`, `GetArrayLength()`, ...)